# Can this differentiation be simplified?

Tags: calculus

$x = \sqrt{y^2+2}$.

I have $\dfrac{\mathrm d (y^2 + 2)^{1/2}}{\mathrm d y\qquad\qquad} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot (y^2 + 2)^{-1/2}$.

Can it be simplified?

Comment: It is not correct, so simplifying won't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x = \sqrt{y^2 + 2}$ then $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{2}(y^2 + 2)^{-1/2} \cdot \frac{d}{dy}(y^2 + 2) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2 + 2}}$

Comment: Where does the d/dy come from? Is that the chain rule of ($y^2+2$)? Shouldn't it be 2y instead?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dy}$ comes from the chain rule, and yes derivative of $(y^2 +2) $ is $2y$

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{\operatorname d (y^2+2)^{1/2}}{\operatorname d y} = y~(y^2+2)^{-1/2}$ via the Chain Rule.